# Using commas with apostrophes for three or more plural possessive nouns

Tags: commas, possessives, apostrophe

Is it

> teachers', students', and administrators' experiences

or

> teachers,' students,' and administrators' experiences

? I think it is the first example with apostrophe, then comma?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Do not confuse apostrophes with quotation marks.

Answer (score 3):

The comma does not go inside the apostrophe.  And you have too many commas.

It is OK to say

teachers', students' and administrators' experiences...

That is, your second comma is not needed, unless you are devoted to the [Oxford Comma](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Oxford+Comma).

> The 'Oxford comma' is an optional comma before the word 'and' at the
>   end of a list: We sell books, videos, and magazines. It's known as the
>   Oxford comma because it was traditionally used by printers, readers,
>   and editors at Oxford University Press.

It would be neater to say:

The experiences of teachers, students and administrators...

Comment: Your link does at least go on to point out that the extra comma is *[extremely]* useful in obvious contexts such as *These items are available in black and white, red and yellow, and blue and green* (three different types). Personally I *wouldn't* use one in OP's specific case because all three nouns are "interrelated" (through an educational establishment) - so if I were *speaking*, I'd rattle them all off quickly because they're a "composite unit". But if they'd been, say, *teachers, politicians, and accountants* (no obvious connection), I'd pause before the last. And write an Oxford comma.

Comment: ...that's to say, the idea that it's some quaint "outmoded" typographic convention is really just so much tosh. It's a useful feature of the written form, and writers who eschew it "ideologically" deprive both themselves and their readers.